# How to preview Pdf file without download

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf

I have a url which makes a rest call and when I go to this url it downloads a pdf file.

What I want to do here is preview this file before download. In IE it works like this. It asks me to open or save. But I have a problem with Chrome because it downloads the file directly.

How can I solve this problem?

Can I solve it with javascript or should I make it with Java?

I also tried to open a stream and getting a bytearray but I couldn't achieve the preview like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "preview"? In IE if you press  "open", the file does get downloaded (just as with hitting "save"), but IE just opens the file directly after downloading with your default pdf reader?

Comment: Maybe do you mean "open the PDF reader inside a browser window"? Note that it actually downloads the PDF, but to a directory managed by the browser and not to the user directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this via javascript using [pdfjs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) library from Mozilla. [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported) list of supported browsers. It will be look like this

```
#rest API 

/some/url/to/pdf/file.pdf #GET rest call to download pdf file

/preview/some/pdf/file    #GET rest call to retrieve html page with pdfs library
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question. I think what you are saying is that Chrome just opens the pdf file in the frame, rather than asking you about open/save. If I'm interpreting right, you want the "Do you want to save this file?" option in all browsers. If so, you might want to set the [Content-Disposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header to "attachment".